# How to create nested JSON return with aggregate function and dynamic key values using `jsonb_build_object`

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is what and example of the table looks like.

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|    country_code     |      region      |   num_launches   |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |         5        |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Quebec'     |         9        |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |         15       |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |    'Saarland'    |         12       |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Berlin'     |         23       |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        'JP'         |     'Tokyo'      |         19       |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I am able to write a query that returns each `country_code` with all `regions` nested within, but I am unable to get exactly what I am looking for.

My intended return looks like.

```
[
  { 'CA': [
      { 'Ontario': 5 },
      { 'Quebec': 9 }
    ]
  },
  { 'DE': [
      { 'Bavaria': 15 },
      { 'Saarland': 12 },
      { 'Berlin': 23 }
    ]
  },
  { 'JP': [
      { 'Tokyo': 19 }
    ]
  }
]
```

How could this be calculated if the `num_launches` was not available?

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|    country_code     |      region      |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Ontario'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Quebec'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'CA'         |     'Quebec'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Bavaria'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |    'Saarland'    |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Berlin'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'DE'         |     'Berlin'     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        'JP'         |     'Tokyo'      |
+---------------------+------------------+
```

Expected Return

```
[
  { 'CA': [
      { 'Ontario': 3 },
      { 'Quebec': 2 }
    ]
  },
  { 'DE': [
      { 'Bavaria': 4 },
      { 'Saarland': 1 },
      { 'Berlin': 2 }
    ]
  },
  { 'JP': [
      { 'Tokyo': 1 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `json_agg` with [json_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) function in a subquery to get the array then do it again in the main query.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   country_code varchar(50),
   region  varchar(50),
  num_launches int
);


insert into t values ('CA','Ontario',5);      
insert into t values ('CA','Quebec',9);       
insert into t values ('DE','Bavaria',15);     
insert into t values ('DE','Saarland',12);    
insert into t values ('DE','Berlin',23);      
insert into t values ('JP','Tokyo',19);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(country_code,arr)) results
from (
  SELECT country_code,
         json_agg(json_build_object(region,num_launches)) arr 
  FROM T
  group by country_code
) t1;
```

**results**

```
[{"CA":[{"Ontario":5},{"Quebec":9}]},{"DE":[{"Bavaria":15},{"Saarland":12},{"Berlin":23}]},{"JP":[{"Tokyo":19}]}]
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kUPfjzPciTJwctbox9vydi/1)

Comment: How would I adjust the query if the `num_launches` column were not immediately available. I put an example in the question body.